# Exception: Password must not be null in TRESTClient in Talend

Tags: talend

I want to use tRESTClient in Talend open studio 6.3, but I always get the following exception although I already set username/password (in the option Use Authantication - Basic HTTP)

```
[WARN ]: org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils - Default key managers cannot be initialized: Password must not be null
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password must not be null
```

Thank u

Comment: If you need a SSL authentification, perhaps you could check the tSetKeystore component ?

Comment: Basic Authentication has nothing to do with SSL, and the error you are receiving seems to be SSL based.  What protocol are you using to connect?  is it https or http?